# How do NASA staff ask the director questions using "Social Q&A"?

Tags: nasa

In Scott Manly's new video [Updates - JPL Visit, Mars 2020, Moon in 5 Year, EVA Changes, Indian ASAT](https://youtu.be/MD7CH9ooUwM?t=92) after about `01:30` he shows a screen shot of some kind of interface of a "Social Q&A" that apparently has questions written by NASA staff for the NASA director.

Is this some standard internal NASA Q&A utility? If so, does the director generally answer questions asked in this way? Does the voting (mentioned in the screen shot) help determine which questions will make it to the director's attention?

[image: Q&A at NASA]

> - Will the administration and congress back up this audacious goal with an appropriate influx of funding?
> - Accelerating our return to the Moon is an unfunded mandate. How will we do it without gutting our other important missions?
> - Please explain in detail what “We’ll change the Agency, not the mission” entails
> - VP Pence directed us to land a crew on the Moon within the next 5 years “by any means necessary”, what means will you be using?
> - NASA peaked at 34,000 engineers during Apollo, today we have half that. Are we going to receive more resources?

Comment: I've seen this type of Q&A done at a conference before using https://www.sli.do/ though I have no idea if that's what NASA use or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an internal website sent in a link to all NASA employees and contractors.  Some of the questions were read verbatim, others were combined into larger meta-questions.

I can't speak to how they "usually" do these, as this is the first one I've ever really participated in.  One of the last questions asked from online was in fact mine.